# HTML Get rid of white space collapsing

Tags: html, whitespace

If you write this:

a
b

it will normally render as "a b".  I want it to render as "ab".  Any thoughts?

Comment: The comment “I am writing an app with Rails…” indicates that the question asked has little if anything to do with the real problem.

Comment: Surround it with `<pre>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

## Nope sorry, you can't

If there is one character deemed to be white space (either a tab, space or line break) then a space will be added. You can use javascript to remove the spaces but it's not suggested. What ever is printing it out should be taking care of that for you.

What platform are you using, we may be able to help better if we knew the circumstances.

Comment: I am writing an app with Rails, and want to be able to set the color of each character in a string individually.  The way I wanted to do it was to have a loop that goes through each character and uses <font> tags to set the color.  However, when I do that, because of the whitespace issue, "Example" becomes "E x a m p l e".  I'm sure there's a slicker way to do this, but I'm a beginner and couldn't think of any.

Comment: Once you have the string replace all spaces in it with an empty string. Or post the Rails and I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a comment:

```
a<!--
-->b​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: If you are able to wrap your white space in comment tags, you should defiantly be able to remove the white space all together. This is very heavy to send to the client and should not be used.

Comment: It has its uses. Especially when dealing with inline-blocks.

Comment: ...What? Using comments to help your layout is never the answer. I am interested about this inline-block thing though, can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Hmm readability shouldn't get in the way of correct markup.  http://jsfiddle.net/fxvhn/1/

inline-block is meant for blocks to be floated within inline text, like images and so on, so the space (like adding spaces in text) is visible for this reason. This functionality is meant to be built in, and if you are trying to stack elements like in your example, then you should really be floating them.

Comment: An inline-block was desired--this is the solution. It's also valid markup.

Comment: Tables work too but they are still not very nice. Function over form, go with the semantic stuff, rather than the hacky stuff

Answer (score 0):

This is not about white space collapsing, since there is just a line break between the characters. Collapsing is about multiple consecutive whitespace being treated as one space.

There is no way in HTML to say that normal HTML whitespace rules be not applied in the sense of ignoring a line break.

In CSS, you could set e.g. `word-spacing: -0.25em`, though `0.25em` is just a rough approximation of the width of a space.

To make “a” and “b” rendered without a space between them, write them as “ab”.